# Help with this conditional

Tags: meaning

The speaker was holding his girlfriends hand as she was sick in bed and he said:

> いい加減寝てもわらないと手が痛いんですが

However I am looking at this and wondering whether this should be parsed as two separate parts i.e.
いい加減寝てもわらないと（駄目）。手が痛いんですが。

Or whether this is actually already a complete conditional. In this case, I'm not quite sure I understand how it works. To me it reads something like, if you don't go to sleep already my hand　will/does hurt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "normal" conditional sentence, and nothing is omitted. Your translation seems perfectly legitimate. 手が痛い mainly refers to something that can happen in the future (although he is starting to feel pain now).